# Reporting Services always ask for loggin

Tags: reporting-services

i installed Reporting Services (SQL Server 2012 with advanced services), but i can't view report page locally.

I try view the page:

```
    http://jorge-pc//ReportServer_SQLEXPRESS
```

but i have this error: The permissions granted to user 'Domain\user' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

I read some pages and tried, right click in IE and run as administrator, but the Reporting Services always ask for loggin (the pages say that Reporting Services should not ask, and show the home page), i write my user and password and get the previous error.

I always get the same error.

What can cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

You should either add anonymous access to your development ssrs service or add your login as an authorized user for you reports via the ssrsmanager.

Comment: Thanks for your comment; but SSRS manager is the web page? in this case:
    http://jorge-pc//ReportServer_SQLEXPRESS
because in this page is when 1 can't go

Comment: Add your windows user account as ReportAdmin access to the root folder is ssrsmanager.